# Apache random 403 errors

Tags: apache-2.2, php

We are using php 5.4 and a custom php page .
When there is concurrent 300 users for some of the requests it throws 403 forbidden. This page does not use db connection . 
The apache maxclients is set to 600 and serve is 8 core 32GB.

SW : Apache 2.2

Any inputs ?

Answer (score 0):

This was due to apache module called mod_evasive. We were doing load testing and traffic was coming from 1 IP.